# Как построить три графика scatter в одном?

Tags: python, numpy

Есть три массива yy_norm, yy_prof, yy_text_rez - numpy.ndarray
Их объеиняет yy = yTrain[50000:]-numpy.ndarray

```
yy = yTrain[50000:] # Зарплата
pred = yy_norm[50000:]
plt.scatter(yy, pred)
plt.xlabel('Правильные значение')
plt.ylabel('Предсказания')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(plt.xlim())
plt.ylim(plt.ylim())
plt.plot([-1000, 5000], [-1000, 5000])
plt.show()
    yy = yTrain[50000:] # Зарплата
    pred = yy_prof[50000:]
    plt.scatter(yy, pred)
    plt.xlabel('Правильные значение')
    plt.ylabel('Предсказания')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlim(plt.xlim())
    plt.ylim(plt.ylim())
    plt.plot([-1000, 5000], [-1000, 5000])
    plt.show()

    yy = yTrain[50000:] # Зарплата
    pred = yy_text_rez[50000:]
    plt.scatter(yy, pred)
    plt.xlabel('Правильные значение')
    plt.ylabel('Предсказания')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlim(plt.xlim())
    plt.ylim(plt.ylim())
    plt.plot([-1000, 5000], [-1000, 5000])
    plt.show()
```

Как построить три массива yy_norm, yy_prof, yy_text_rez с разными цветами на одном графике scatter?
Как посоветовали:

```
yy = yTrain[50000:] # Зарплата
pred = yy_norm[50000:]
plt.scatter(yy, pred)
pred2 = yy_prof[50000:]
plt.scatter(yy, pred2)
pred3 = yy_text_rez[50000:]
plt.scatter(yy, pred3)

plt.xlabel('Правильные значение')
plt.ylabel('Предсказания')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(plt.xlim())
plt.ylim(plt.ylim())
plt.plot([-1000, 50000], [-1000, 50000])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы несколько график вывести на одном поле - уберите все промежуточные  plt.show(). А вот что там вы рисуете - это уж решайте сами.

Comment: Разными цветами как

Comment: А вы хоть попробуйте то, что я вам насоветовал. Вопрос отпадет сам собой. Незачто.